# How to optimize search query such like LIKE in symfony (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, symfony

I am practicing with symfony doctrine orm using mysql. Current my feature is search function. Enter a text and search by email, last_name or first_name columns. I need many info so I need left join many table and here is query :

```
SELECT u0_.id AS id_0, u0_.email AS email_1, u2_.first_name AS first_name_8, 
        u2_.last_name AS last_name_9 ... (other selects)...  
FROM user u0_ 
    LEFT JOIN user_detail u2_ ON u0_.id = u2_.user_id 
    ... (other LEFT JOIN) ... 
WHERE ... (other conditions)... 
AND u0_.email LIKE '%abc@gmail.com%' 
OR u2_.first_name LIKE '%abc@gmail.com%' 
OR u2_.last_name LIKE '%abc@gmail.com%'
```

But execute time took too long (~ 6s). I realized query is slow maybe cause LIKE conditions. So how could I do to optimize performance of query?

Comment: That's definitely too much I suspect, that's the problem with _other_ JOINS, start with selecting without JOIN, then add next JOINS and check where's the problem. BTW I don't know your context, however it sould be probably sed with preparet staement for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you always want to avoid starting a LIKE query with a wildcard (%).

Reason is it prevents efficient index usage. LIKE filters can only use the characters *before the first wildcard* in the query during tree traversal. Which means, the later the wildcard in the LIKE statement, the better the performance.
So you should avoid starting a LIKE statement with a wildcard: your query won't be able to use any index, so it will be slower.

I don't know if you can avoid LIKE statements starting with a wildcard in your particular use case, but if you can then you really should.

There are solutions to avoid this if you're interested.
For instance, your could adapt your columns to use Full-Text Indexing, and use CONTAINS query instead of LIKE on such columns.